# Apache 2 Test Page displays on the website after I overwrite the .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Website: **[http://www.trbi.com.ph/](http://www.trbi.com.ph)**

I edited the **.htaccess** and inputted a code to allow Google Bot and block the spam bots:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*yahoo.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ask.* search_robot

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot
```

Then uploaded the .htaccess using FTP. I refreshed the website and it now displays the Apache 2 Test Page.

What should I do? HELP PLS!

Comment: opps. you have a copy of the original? If you only allow access from search_robots, then actual humans can't see it.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes sir I have the copy of the original htaccess. What should I add to allow humans?

Comment: rather than list every possible user-agent that is a human, you should probably deny the bots. http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_stop_automated_spam-bots_using_.htaccess

Comment: @GarrGodfrey the reason why I deny some bots and allow bots like google bot is that in Google Webmaster Tools, Google Bot can't access robots.txt in the website. Maybe the server is blocking the bots.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey what if I remove Deny from All.. Can human access the website now?